# Include sessions inside an inclusion

Tags: django, session

I cannot seem to access request.sessions inside my inclusion template. Any ideas how I can get this data? The sessions are my own, custom ones.

My inclusion looks like

```
@register.inclusion_tag('base/side_bar.html', takes_context=True)
    def show_side_bar(context):
    models = Model.objects.all()
    makes = Make.objects.all()
    request = context['request']

 return {
     'makes':makes,
     'models':models,
 }
```

This errors out and says

> Caught an exception while rendering: 'request'

And I'm calling this with

```
{% load extras %}
{% show_side_bar %}
```

Comment: When you say 'inclusion template', do you mean 'template used in an inclusion tag' or do you mean 'template included via `{% include %}`'? And is this just a problem with the inclusion template, or does it happen in the main template too?

Comment: You'll need to provide a snippet of code from your view function showing what objects you're passing to your template.

Comment: I'm using {% load extras %}, then {% user_details %}. the user_details() method is inside templatetags/extras.py, cant seems to access request.sessions inside the extras.py mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a `request` variable in your template context, the `django.core.context_processors.request` context processor needs to be in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting. The trick is, it's not there by default. You need to add it to your settings if you want to get it from the context like that. (See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/api/#id1 for more information about context processors.)

Comment: I've added the stuff to the settings file. I've added the context variable to my method. But the context var only holds a bunch of model objects.